# Where to we get the key from "GET /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{key}/deliveryRecords"

Tags: marketing-cloud

According to [this Marketing Cloud API documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSendsDeliveryRecords.htm):

> Key is defined as Customer **key of the entry event send definition. Either this or the SendID is required**.

Where can I find the key in my account?

Comment: customer key is usually synonymous with external key you define in the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email Studio -> Interactions -> Triggered Sends

Use the value from "External Key" column